# How do the lipid nanoparticles in the Pfizer and Moderna vaccines contain and release the mRNA payloads at the right time?

Tags: coronavirus, vaccination, mrna, lipids

The engineering challenge with mRNA vaccines is that mRNA is fragile and degrades quickly. The solution, then, is to encapsulate the mRNA within lipid nanoparticles that carry the payload into cell.

However, this leads to another problem because mRNA and lipid molecules are both negative and will repel each other. In response, researchers developed cationic lipids that would bind the nucleic acids for delivery into acid. There was yet another problem, because testing found that these solutions were causing undesired side effects. The ultimate solution was to develop a lipid specially formulated to be neutral in at physiological pH, but cationic in acidic environments. This means that the lipid nanoparticles will be stable in blood or extracellular fluid, but once it is absorbed into the cell via receptor-mediated endocytosis, the acidic environment of the endosome will protonate the tertiary amine of the lipid into an ammonium cation, and the mRNA is released into the cell.

It's this last part which confuses me. Specifcally, **why does protonating the amine to ammonia cause the mRNA to escape the nanoparticle?** Shouldn't doing this cause the mRNA to be *more* strongly associated with the lipid, since cations and anions attract each other?